# Unterschied zwischen: im Streit um und im Streit über

Tags: difference, word-choice

Können Sie bitte erklären, was der Unterschied zwischen *im Streit um* und *im Streit über* ist? Könnten Sie bitte die Beispiele ins Englische übersetzen? Ich bedanke mich im Voraus.

Answer (score 5):

**streiten um**

Hier wollen mehrere (meist zwei) das Gleiche und streiten sich deswegen.

Sie streiten sich z. B. um

> - auf dem Boden liegendes Geld
> - das letzte Stück Kuchen
> - einen Platz im Rettungsboot

**streiten über**

Hier haben mehrere (meist zwei) eine unterschiedliche Meinung und streiten sich deswegen.
Streitfragen können z. B. sein:

> - Gibt es einen Gott?
> - Leben wir in der besten aller möglichen Welten?
> - Was war zuerst da, das Ei oder das Huhn?

Comment: Deutsche Beispiele ins Englische zu übersetzen ohne nativ Englischsprechender zu sein, ist ohnehin problematisch.

Comment: Man könnte auch zusammenfassend sagen, dass es *Streit **um ein Objekt*** aber *Streit **über ein Thema*** gibt.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: Statt _»Objekt«_ würden manche wohl _»Gegenstand«_ sagen, da Ersteres stärker an Stoffliches denken lässt, und da unter ein Thema mehrere strittige Aspekte fallen können, wäre _»Aspekt«_ vielleicht besser.

Comment: Willst Du mit mir über die richtige Wortwahl streiten? Oder nur um das letzte Wort (=den letzten Kommentar)? ;-)

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: Ich rede nur von der Wortwahl, die Grundaussage deines Kommentars scheint mir richtig.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Man muss differenzieren.

Wenn mit "Streit" eine Diskussion, eine verbale Auseinandersetzung über irgendwelche Themen gemeint ist, gibt es keinen Unterschied. **um** und **über** können synonym gebraucht werden.

> Im Streit um neue Richtlinien der EU
>
> Im Streit über neue Richtlinien der EU

Ist mit "Streit" der Kampf um eine Sache gemeint, die jemand bekommen möchte, sollte nur **um** verwendet werden.

> Im Streit um die Nachfolge Kiesingers als CDU-Vorsitzender unterlag Kohl ...

Als englische Übersetzung taugen:

> in the dispute over
>
> in the dispute about

Ich erhebe hierbei keinen Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit.

Comment: Zwei können im Streit _über_ eine Kanditatur liegen, ohne dass einer der beiden die Kandidatur beansprucht, was bei _um_ i. d. R. nicht der Fall ist..

Comment: Sie schreiben doch selber: _"Wenn mit 'Streit' ... **über** irgendwelche Themen gemeint ist ..."_, fahren dann aber fälschlicherweise fort mit _"... gibt es keinen Unterschied."_ Sie hätten damit fortfahren müssen, dass dann nur *im Streit **über*** geht. Und wenn **um** irgendwas gestritten wird, dann geht eben nur *im Streit **um***.